# what are the differences between the account properties of ServiceProcessInstaller

Tags: properties, windows-services

Hi i am learning to create a windows service i searched a lot and did not get a clear understanding of the `Account` property in the ServiceProcessInstaller Class can anybody please explain what is the difference between 
1.User
2.LocasService etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ServiceAccount Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceaccount%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) page on MSDN has a table that describes each account.

It is best practice to use an account with the lowest privileges that is appropriate to the functionality of your service. Normally that means using the [LocalService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms684188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) account unless you're doing something that requires the privileges of [LocalSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

LocalSystem basically has free reign over the machine, whereas LocalService/NetworkService have roughly the same privileges of a standard user account. As you'd expect, running the service in the context of a specific user would provide the service with that user's privileges.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Kevin Richardson
I have another doubt.
when i a want to install the service under the user account i am providing my user name and password (the one used to login to windows)
but it throws an exception stating that `The account name is invalid    or the password is incorrect`?

Comment: When specifying the username, you'll need to use the format `computername\username` or `domain\username`. For a local user on the machine, I believe you can use `.\username`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best one is:

**LocalService**
An account that acts as a non-privileged user on the local computer, and presents anonymous credentials to any remote server.

**LocalSystem** 
An account, used by the service control manager, that has extensive privileges on the local computer and acts as the computer on the network.

**NetworkService**
An account that provides extensive local privileges, and presents the computer's credentials to any remote server.

**User**
An account defined by a specific user on the network. Specifying User for the ServiceProcessInstaller.Account member causes the system to prompt for a valid user name and password when the service is installed, unless you set values for both the Username and Password properties of your ServiceProcessInstaller instance.

from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceaccount(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Are you able to explain the difference between "*acts as the computer on the network*" and "*presents the computer's credentials to any remote server*"?